# High chart area range graph with different border color

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using high chart to draw graphs.currently using area range graph.I want to give different color to border of area range graph.and fill the interior with white.How can i achieve this.Current graph looks like below.I want to fill it with white and different border color.

[image]

```
         name: 'Data',
         pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
         data: noData,
         type: 'arearange',
         lineWidth: 0,
         linkedTo: ':previous',
         color : '#D2D2D2',                
         zIndex: 0,
         enableMouseTracking: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple to achieve. These properties can be controlled form the plotOption settings.

```
plotOptions: {
    arearange: {
        lineColor: 'blue',
        fillColor: 'grey'
    }
},
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/fguk8j1e/) is a working jsfiddle for your reference.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

**Edit:**
If you are having multiple arearange then you can do as shown below

```
series: [{
    name: 'Temperatures',
    data: data,
    fillColor: 'grey',
    lineColor: 'red'
},{
    name: 'Humidity',
    data: data2,
    fillColor: 'grey',
    lineColor: 'red'
}]
```

Comment: I am using multiple arearange in one graph

Comment: sorry, I did not understand that

Comment: the border will comes in top and bottom only.I want it in left and right too

Comment: basicaally it will give border if there are any values present. If there are no values in the data it will not draw a connecting line. A line each will be drawn along the points of data1 and data2 respectively. I you want such line continuously connects both the data points add those intersecting data points to both the data sets.

Comment: My graph will be not contain data for some days and so arearange graph will show blank between them.It is a requirement.But border on right and left when there is no data to connect the graph.In the demo you have shared also do not have blue borders on left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you question and the comments from the other answer:

You could add a border for plot area and remove x axis edge padding for series plot like in this demo:

`JSFiddle demo`: http://jsfiddle.net/u17h0h9b/

```js
$(function() {
  var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: '#afa',
      plotBorderColor: '#f0f',
      plotBorderWidth: 2
    },
    xAxis: {
     minPadding: 0,
      maxPadding: 0
    },
    series: [{
     type: 'area',
      color: '#f0f',
      fillColor: 'rgba(0,100,200,0.3)',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: This won't work for me.My area graph will show blank in between if there is no data for that period.So i need borders in left right of each area plotted in graph.

Comment: @James Please post a JSFiddle demo with an exemplary data set, so I could suggest a better solution.